# Jsp extends page directives exception: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to make an example by using JSP extends page directives, First I have build a simple java class file in my project source area. Project is building in Eclipse IDE.

Code is here:

```
package com.coderbd.extend;

public class Test {

    public String testMethod(){
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

And the at JSP page first, I have extended the class using extend page directives like: `<%@ page extends="com.coderbd.extend.Test" %>`
Then In my `index.jsp` page, I have created object of `Test` class like:

```
<%
    Test t= new Test();
    t.testMethod();
%>
```

And at last tried to print:

```
<%
    out.println(""+ testMethod());
%>
```

And I have used following jars at my `lib` under `WEB-INF` folder.

1. `jasper.jar`
2. `org.apache.jasper.jar`
3. `javax.servlet-api-3.0.jar`
4. `javax.el-api.jar`
5. `javax.servlet-3.0.jar`

But I see, my Tomcat server gives following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [32] in the generated java file: [E:\The Java Spring Tutorial Learn Java's Popular Web Framework\JSP\work-space\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\jsp-sec-4-lec-3\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getServletConfig() is undefined for the type index_jsp

An error occurred at line: [33] in the generated java file: [E:\The Java Spring Tutorial Learn Java's Popular Web Framework\JSP\work-space\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\jsp-sec-4-lec-3\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getServletConfig() is undefined for the type index_jsp

An error occurred at line: [54] in the generated java file: [E:\The Java Spring Tutorial Learn Java's Popular Web Framework\JSP\work-space\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\jsp-sec-4-lec-3\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getPageContext(Servlet, ServletRequest, ServletResponse, String, boolean, int, boolean) in the type JspFactory is not applicable for the arguments (index_jsp, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, null, boolean, int, boolean)

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please help me to  fix the example using jsp extends page directive.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all these jars from WEB-INF/lib. Those are jar files that Tomcat uses internally. They should not be in your webapp.

And remove `extends="com.coderbd.extend.Test"`: it doesn't make any sense. Your JSP creates an instance of `Test` and **uses** it. It doesn't need to (and can't) *extend* it.

Comment: I have solved the problem using extends keywords, actually I wanted to use extends. Thank everybody to give me suggestions.